# nav2d exploration with turtlebot and lidar: no map available

Tags: slam, navigation, exploration, ros-kinetic, 2dlidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys, we have a project at our university for a autonomous SLAM Turtlebot2 with a Lidar A2 Laserscanner by slamtec.
We tried the nav2d_tutorials and the tutorial3 is our perfect setup. its working perfectly in the simulator, but for the next step we need to combine all the nodes of the tutorial3 with the rplidar and turtlebot node.

This is the edited tutorial3.launch:

```
<launch>
<!--1.  Kommando zum Starten der ersten Map rosservice call /StartMapping -->
<!--2.  Kommando zum Starten des rumfahrens rosservice call /StartExploration -->

<!-- Some general parameters -->
<rosparam file="$(find nav2d_tutorials)/param/ros.yaml"/>

<!-- Start the Operator to control the simulated robot -->
<node name="Operator" pkg="nav2d_operator" type="operator" >
    <remap from="/cmd_vel" to="/mobile_base/commands/velocity" />
    <rosparam file="$(find nav2d_tutorials)/param/operator.yaml"/>
    <rosparam file="$(find nav2d_tutorials)/param/costmap.yaml" ns="local_map" />
</node>

<!-- Start Mapper to genreate map from laser scans -->
<node name="Mapper" pkg="nav2d_karto" type="mapper">

    <rosparam file="$(find nav2d_tutorials)/param/mapper.yaml"/>
</node>

<!-- Start the Navigator to move the robot autonomously -->
<node name="Navigator" pkg="nav2d_navigator" type="navigator">
    <rosparam file="$(find nav2d_tutorials)/param/navigator.yaml"/>
</node>

<node name="Explore" pkg="nav2d_navigator" type="explore_client" />
<node name="SetGoal" pkg="nav2d_navigator" type="set_goal_client" />

<!-- Start the joystick-driver and remote-controller for operation-->
<node name="Joystick" pkg="joy" type="joy_node" />
<node name="Remote" pkg="nav2d_remote" type="remote_joy" />

<!-- RVIZ to view the visualization -->
<node name="RVIZ" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args=" -d $(find nav2d_tutorials)/param/tutorial3.rviz" />
</launch>
```

The simulator node is removed and instead, we launch the *turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch*.
For the Lidar Scanner results we are starting the rplidar node of [robopeak](https://github.com/robopeak/rplidar_ros).
The /scan topic is also providing LaserScan Messages. These two nodes are started on a raspberry pi on the turtlebot. The rest is started on a workstation (roscore also on the pi and the workstations ROS_MASTER_URI points to the pi).

So the problem is, somehow the karo mapper cant create a map and therefore the robot cant start exploring.
With the StartMapping Call the turtlebot makes his initial position finding, but the map is not created and therefore the exploration wont work.  Rviz says no map provided.

The params files are still the same of the tutorial3.
This is the rosgraph of our setting:

[image: image description]

We also tried to remap the /scan topic to /base_scan, but it wasnt working.

Can anybody help us with this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293489/nav2d-exploration-with-turtlebot-and-lidar:-no-map-available/) by [artur](https://answers.ros.org/users/35734/artur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-06-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pengjiawei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31790/pengjiawei/) on 2018-06-07**:
what can you see if you do rostopic echo /base_scan and rostopic echo /map

**Comment by [artur](https://answers.ros.org/users/35734/artur/) on 2018-06-08**:
If we remap the /scan topic of the rplidar node zu /base_scan, the LaserScan Results are coming via base_scan, otherwise via /scan.

But the /map is still empty with, and without the remap.

**Comment by [artur](https://answers.ros.org/users/35734/artur/) on 2018-06-11**:
We found out, that there are problems with the /Mapper Node and the LaserScan Data of the rplidar Node: rosnode info /Mapper

```
Subscriptions: 
 * /base_scan [unknown type]
 * /initialpose [geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped]
 * /karto_in [unknown type]
...
```

**Comment by [artur](https://answers.ros.org/users/35734/artur/) on 2018-06-18**:
Tried it with gazebo turtlebot_world simulator instead of sage and there are the same problems. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://answers.ros.org/question/229676/map-not-received-when-using-nav2d-with-gazebo/?answer=269164#post-id-269164

This was the solution for our problem.

---

Originally posted by [artur](https://answers.ros.org/users/35734/artur/) with karma: 16 on 2018-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0